Bazel build: Java file is located outside of module source root, so it won't be compiled
Facing issue when adding test files in test folder path /industries-access-propagation-impl/test/unit/java/src/strictunit/accesspropagation/logger/ . I see the message "Java file is located outside of module source root, so it won't be compiled" and the test files don't get compiled.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have added the directory in .bazelproject. Where else it needs to be added to get the entry for test files (/industries-access-propagation-impl/test/unit/java/src) to be compiled?
I tried right click on the src folder and select "Mark Directory as" -> "Sources Root" or "Test Sources Root".
But these changes don't persist when I do bazel sync or bazel build (on cli) and the test files get excluded. I have added the entries in /core-app/members.bzl. What am I missing in order to compile the test files?

Not sure what your project-specific /core-app/members.bzl file does. Maybe you can share the file or a minimal reproducible example.

You have to add our source files to a BUILD (or BUILD.bazel) file. Every directory can have its own BUILD file. By creating a BUILD file you define the corresponding directory as Bazel package.
In a BUILD file you can define targets. Standard Java Bazel targets are defined via java_library or java_binary.
For instance, when you have a HelloWorld.java you can
define something like this:
java_binary(
    name = "hello_world",
    src = ["HelloWorld.java"],
    main_class = "HelloWorld",
)

.bazelproject is JetBrains specific. First try to get it working with pure Bazel, i.e. bazel test //.... Usually, you do not modified the .bazelproject to get new tests executed.
